# BeautifulSoup finding children with only 'dot', without 'find()' function

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to initiate specific element to a variable, without using 'find()' or findAll()' function, just with BeautifulSoup and 'dots'.
 What I'm confused is the order of priority.
 There's a lot of 'finding children' questions using findAll() function, but there seems no 'dot' things. So finally I write this question.

Here's the example.

-----html------

```
<div class="item-container">
    <!--product image-->
    <a class="item-img" href="https://www.newegg.com/asus-geforce-rtx-2080-ti-dual-rtx2080ti-o11g/p/N82E16814126247?Item=N82E16814126247">
        <div class="item-badges">
            <div class= "item-test">
             </div>
        </div>
        <img alt="ASUS Dual GeForce RTX 2080 Ti DirectX 12 DUAL-RTX2080TI-O11G 11GB 352-Bit GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 HDCP Ready SLI Support Video Card" class="lazy-img" data-effect="fadeIn" data-src="//c1.neweggimages.com/NeweggImage/ProductImageCompressAll300/14-126-247-V50.jpg" src="//c1.neweggimages.com/WebResource/Themes/2005/Nest/blank.gif" title="ASUS Dual GeForce RTX 2080 Ti DirectX 12 DUAL-RTX2080TI-O11G 11GB 352-Bit GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 HDCP Ready SLI Support Video Card">
        </img>
    </a>
    <div class="item-info">
        <!--brand info-->
        <div class="item-branding">
            <a class="item-brand" href="https://www.newegg.com/ASUS/BrandStore/ID-1315">
                <img alt="ASUS" class="lazy-img" data-effect="fadeIn" data-src="//c1.neweggimages.com/Brandimage_70x28//Brand1315.gif" src="//c1.neweggimages.com/WebResource/Themes/2005/Nest/blank.gif" title="ASUS">
                </img></a>
            <!--rating info-->
            <a class="item-rating" href="https://www.newegg.com/asus-geforce-rtx-2080-ti-dual-rtx2080ti-o11g/p/N82E16814126247?Item=N82E16814126247&amp;SortField=0&amp;SummaryType=0&amp;PageSize=10&amp;SelectedRating=-1&amp;VideoOnlyMark=False&amp;IsFeedbackTab=true#scrollFullInfo" title="Rating + 2"><i class="rating rating-2"></i><span class="item-rating-num">(32)</span></a>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

------python--------

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphic%20card"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read() 
uClinet.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

---

from here, I'm gonna find the div wiht class 'item-branding'.
so I went like this

```
>>> page_soup.div.div
```

What do you get by this? Seems it depends on the version of python or something else. It varies among users.

someone gets , but I got ''.
Do you see this difference?

The first one(which got ) , gets the div among first level children. div class 'item-badges' is child of the child a(class 'item img'), so it's second level child. So the spell 'page_soup.div' skipped div(item-branding) in the first 'a(item-image)', and caught  as the first 'div'. And so 'page_soup.div.div' could get right into the 'div class="item-branding"'.

However, the second one, my computer doesn't do the same thing with the same spell.

my spell 'page_soup.div.div' found out 'div class="item-test"'.
My spell 'page_soup.div' got into just the nearest div from the top, without regarding the level of children. It just got into the first div, that's inside the child 'a(class item-badges)'. So the 'page_soup.div.div' got into the 'div class="item-test"', first div in the item-badges.

Same spell, but different logic.

Do you know what makes this difference? And how to fix this?

Thank you genius.

p.s   i use python 3.7   32x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is well documented here: [BS: navigating using tag names](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names)

> The simplest way to navigate the parse tree is to say the name of the tag you want. If you want the `<head>` tag, just say `soup.head`.
>
> You can do use this trick again and again to zoom in on a certain part of the parse tree. `soup.body.b` gets the **first** `<b>` tag beneath the `<body>` tag.
>
> Using a tag name as an attribute will give you only the ***first*** tag by that name.
>
> If you need to get all the `<a>` tags, or anything more complicated than the *first tag* with a certain name, you’ll need to use one of the methods described in [Searching the tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree), such as `find_all()`
>
> (emphasis and omissions mine)

So your `page_soup.div.div` finds the *first ever `div`* thats inside a `div` - and `page_soup.div` finds the *first ever* `div`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Dormouse's story</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>first div</div>
  <p>unrelated
  </p>
  <div>second div
    <div>with another div inside</div>
  </div>

  <div>can't get this one by soup.div.div
    <div>with another div inside</div>
  </div>
</body
```

for that code you can get the first one by `soup.div` and you get the second one by `.div.div`. The last one you can only get by doing a `findall()`.